# What is the problem with rounding floats in mysql?

Tags: mysql, floating-point, rounding

Actually we want to switch from float to decimal in our database. While we checked the values, if everything is correct, we figured out that mysql round has a strange behavior and we do not know why.

```
Table name: test
column name: test
column type: float

SQL: SELECT ROUND(test, 2) FROM test

-----------------------------------------
|    test    |  result of round(test,2) |
-----------------------------------------
|   12.225   |           12.23          |
-----------------------------------------
|   12.125   |           12.12          |
-----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See explanation from [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html).

For conversion, you might get better results with CAST:

```
SELECT CAST(test as decimal(10,2)) FROM test
```